# Inserting data into ms word table format using unix

Tags: bash, unix

[image]can we create a tabular format in ms word and insert data into that ms word using UNIX scripting.

[image]

Comment: Could be, could be not, can't say for sure.

Comment: of course. just use tab separated data.

Comment: tab seperate will give you space ryt but i need tabular format

Comment: maybe... I certainly would not. It seems like a much better idea to use a language like python and some open document format

Comment: You should post a sample of data format expected.

Comment: sample table format posted

Answer (score 0):

In bash this is very simple. You can use `echo` to write the commands in a sample-file **sample.csv** with e.g.:

```
>echo "Lkp_BLIND; 2; N" > sample.csv
>echo "Lkp_CDL; 2; N" >> sample.csv
>cat sample.csv
Lkp_BLIND; 2; N
Lkp_CDL; 2; N
```

Read this file into excel, everything should be fine. You can change the seperator ofc or play around with variables.

**Edit**

To give you a start for the Bash script, you can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="sample.csv"
touch $file

ar1=(Lkp_BLIND Lkp_CDL testword)
ar2=(2 2 13)
ar3=(N N X)

for i in {0..2}
do
        echo "${ar1[$i]} ; ${ar2[$i]} ; ${ar3[$i]}" >> $file
done
```

The sample-file which can be load into excel will be:

```
Lkp_BLIND ; 2 ; N
Lkp_CDL ; 2 ; N
testword ; 13 ; X
```

Comment: but my output is not csv it is ms word

Comment: do i need to use any other language

Comment: No but you have to understand the syntax/format from MS Word. I don't know this syntax, looks like binary stuff. Just create a file you want to re-create via script and have a look at that file. It should be no problem to generate stuff like this in ASCII format for example...